# command line ffmpeg or sox convert audio tracks from stereo to 7.1 upmix

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, audiotrack, sox

Hi I have 3 flac multichannel files that I need to mix:

1) 7.1 channels

2) 7.1 channels

3) Stereo channels

to avoid eventual problems on mixing (some of these already exist) I like to convert the stereo track to 7.1, in this mode all the 3 files are 7.1 files ready to mix.

I serching for a command line like:

ffmpeg input_stereo.flac output_7.1.flac

or

sox  input_stereo.flac output_7.1.flac

I suppose the setting are:

Left         ----->       FL  (front left)

Right        ----->       FR  (front right)

Left + right ----->       FC  (front center)

(empty)      ----->       LFE (subwoofer)

Left         ----->       BL  (back left)

Right        ----->       BR  (back right)

Left         ----->       SL  (side left)

Right        ----->   SR  (side right)

is possible post a commmand line that do this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific channel mapping in mind, like in the Q, use the pan `filter`

```
ffmpeg input_stereo.flac -af pan=7.1|FL=FL|FR=FR|FC<FL+FR|LFE=0|BL=FL|BR=FR|SL=FL|SR=FR output_7.1.flac
```

If you want to use FFmpeg's defaults, use

```
ffmpeg input_stereo.flac -ac 8 output_7.1.flac
```